# Jquery Table and text with accented characters issue

Tags: php, jquery

I created a table dynamically with Jquery my variables (in a java array was json_encoded from a php array). After this, my variables are perfect with all the accented characters. So far so good. But as soon I put them in this table the results are bad.

here's the code :

```
<script>
    for (var j = 0; j < 13; j++) {  
        // labels     
        if (j==0) {
            var tab_B = tab_B + "<tr><th>" + label_array2[j] + "</th><th>" + 
            label_array2[j+1] + "</th><th>" + label_array2[j+2] + "</th></tr>";
        }
        // inputs
        if ((j>0) && (j<13)) {
            var tab_B = tab_B + "<tr><td><input type='text' name='" + input_array2[(j*3)] + 
            "' maxlength='33' size='33' value='" + label_array2[(j*3)] + "'/></td><td><input type='text' name='" + 
            input_array2[(j*3)+1] + "' maxlength='5' size='5' value='" + label_array2[(j*3)+1] + 
            "'/></td><td><input type='text' name='" + input_array2[(j*3)+2] + 
            "' maxlength='6' size='6' value='" + label_array2[(j*3)+2] + "'/></td></tr>";
        }
    }

$("#recipetable").html(tab_B);
</script>
```

then I display the table like this :

```
  <table  class="reference" border="1" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id="recipetable"></table>
```

Some texts are truncated :

example :

Before : Pain d'épices

After  : Pain d

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truncation comes from not protecting your quotes. It's a simple thing. Now as for the accents, you must know that json requires utf8 encoding. If this doesn't answer the problem, please make a fiddle for us.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to escape your string to avoid the use of quote for javascript.

Comment: I understand now why ! But If I escape now I can read : Pain%20d%27%E9pices How can I read it again ?

Comment: You can try something like: str_replace("'","\\'", $yourString) in php or in javascript var res = str.replace("'","\\'");

Comment: Now I have this : Pain d\

Comment: I think I'm gonna change my quotes in java by " instead '

Comment: Oups, yes sorry since the ' is not replaced then it's not escaped it should be \' and not \\' :) sorry

Comment: For all the %xx sequences, all you need is some "urldecode()" which will straighten them out to the characters they really mean.  %20 is space, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed escape quote like this,

```
<input type='text' value='Pain d'épices' maxlength="6" size="6" />
```

Demo Link http://jsfiddle.net/BB4ka/